# Is this the right way to explain MergeSort pseudocode? What return does here?

Tags: return, mergesort, pseudocode

On different websites the pseudocode is similar to this one below:

```
merge_sort(num_list)
length <-- length of num_list

if length > 1

    shorter_list_A <-- first half of num_list
    shorter_list_B <-- second half of num_list

    result_A <-- merge_sort(shorter_list_A)
    result_B <-- merge_sort(shorter_list_B)

    sorted_list <-- merge(result_A, result_B)

    return sorted_list
else
    return num_list
end
```

So if we have 4 numbers:  8,3,6,2

```
MergeSort(8,3,6,2)
```

first half of the numbers put to Shorter_list_A(8,3)
and second half of the numbers put to Shorter_list_B(6,2)

```
    shorter_list_A <-- first half of num_list
    shorter_list_B <-- second half of num_list
```

So we have now two lists: shorter_list_A(8,3) and Shorter_list_B (6,2)

```
    result_A <-- merge_sort(shorter_list_A)
```

Merge_sort calls merge_sort again, so what happens there is this:

```
merge_sort(Shorter_list_A)  // also 8,3
length <-- length of Shorter_list_A

if length > 1

    shorter_list_A <-- first half of Shorter_list_A 
//8 put to Shorter_list_A
    shorter_list_B <-- second half of Shorter_list_A
//3 put to Shorter_list_B

    result_A <-- merge_sort(shorter_list_A)
//merge_sort calls merge_sort again
    result_B <-- merge_sort(shorter_list_B)

    sorted_list <-- merge(result_A, result_B)

    return sorted_list
else
    return Shorter_list_A
end
```

So we have now two lists again: shorter_list_A(8) and Shorter_list_B (6)

**From the explanation so far, have I understood that right or complete wrong?**

Then it calls merge_sort again. Since lenght of Shorter_list_A is only 1, it contains only one number which is 8. S what happens there is this:

```
merge_sort(Shorter_list_A)
length <-- length of Shorter_list_A
    return Shorter_list_A
end
```

It returns Shorter_list_A, which is 8.

**What return does exacly here? I'm stuck in there.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember that it recurses down short_list_A until it gets the condition `length <= 1` when you return from a recursive call it returns to the previous call in the call stack, which looks like:

```
result_A <-- merge_sort(shorter_list_A) 
// *** return here ***
result_B <-- merge_sort(shorter_list_B)
sorted_list <-- merge(result_A, result_B)
return sorted_list
```

So it does the same for `result_B` then merges the results before returning up the call stack.

So taking a small example, where indentation shows the recursion depth:

```
merge_sort([4,7,2,3,1,8,6,5])
    a = merge_sort([4,7,2,3])
        a = merge_sort([4,7])
            a = merge_sort([4])   // Doesn't recurse anymore length <= 1
            b = merge_sort([7])
            r = merge(a,b) = merge([4], [7])
            return r = [4,7]
        b = merge_sort([2,3])
            a = merge_sort([2])
            b = merge_sort([3])
            r = merge(a, b) = merge([2], [3])
            return r = [2,3]
        r = merge(a,b) = merge([4,7], [2,3])
        return r = [2,3,4,7]
    b = merge_sort([1,8,6,5])
        a = merge_sort([1,8])
            a = merge_sort([1])
            b = merge_sort([8])
            r = merge(a, b) = merge([1],[8])
            return r = [1,8]
        b = merge_sort([6,5])
            a = merge_sort([6])
            b = merge_sort([5])
            r = merge(a, b) = merge([6],[5])
            return r = [5,6]
        r = merge(a,b) = merge([1,8], [5,6])
        return r = [1,5,6,8]
    r = merge(a, b) = merge([2,3,4,7], [1,5,6,8])
    return r = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: So what I understood is: 1)  there are not only one Shorter_A_list. There are several Shorter_A_lists; one on each recursion level. Is that true? 2) since it never returns num_list until the sorting is completed, could the algorithm work removing thr IF, ELSE and RETURN NUM_LIST statements and just using just WHILE LENGTH >= 1 statement? 3) I still don't understand the function of the statements RETURN NUM_LIST and RETURN SORTED_LIST.

Comment: Yes, there are num_list at every level of recursion, If you put it in a while loop you lose all the previous information so it would not work. The return num_list only gets execute and the very furthest depth of the recursion tree - when it can't split the num_list any further, everywhere else it returns the sorted list.

Comment: From yours and other websites' explanations, I understood what RETURN does. But why not just RETURN but RETURN NUM_LIST and RETURN SORTED_LIST are used? On articles about RETURN on websites like Wikipedia they write something like "Some programming languages allow a function to specify a return value to be passed back to the code that called the function." "Passing a value back to the code", what does it mean?

Comment: See stack above the returned value is assigned to the value `a` or `b` in the previous call so that you can then merge(a,b). If you didn't return a value you would never reflect changes up the call stack. `a` at one depth is different to `a` at a different depth.

Answer (score 1):

Every return will send back to the caller a *sorted* list of the elements it received as the input.

At the bottom most level, when there is only one element, the list is sorted by default and returned. When you will get two sorted lists of one element each in `result_A` and `result_B`, you pass them both to `merge()` method and this method now does the heavy work. This takes the two lists and merges them to give a new list that contains the elements of both lists in sorted order.

**How does `Merge()` look like?**

`Merge()` will instantiate a new list. Let's call it `sorted_list` and then it will start reading from the `head` of both lists it got as input and will take the minimum of both elements at the `head` position and put it in the `sorted_list` it just created. The method will keep consuming the `head` of both input lists until they both are finished. Now the merge of both lists are present in the `sorted_list` in sorted order. I've assumed you want the list sorted from minimum to maximum.

**Running through your example**

At the last level, with single elements, first list of `head -> 8 -> null` and second list of `head -> 3 -> null` will merge to form `head -> 3 -> 8 -> null`

At this level itself, it will merge the two lists of `head -> 6 -> null` and `head -> 2 -> null` to `head -> 2 -> 6 -> null`

Let bottom level be called 0. At level 0, you had single elements only. At level 1 you will have lists of two elements. At level 2 you will have two lists of 2 elements merged to give a single list.

So, from `head -> 3 -> 8 -> null` and `head -> 2 -> 6 -> null`, you will get `head -> 2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 8 -> null`.

And finally this list will be returned. There are no levels further to go up. This is the level where you got the original unsorted input list, so at this return, effectively you will return the sorted list to the caller.

**To Summarize**

```
Level num_list Shorter_List_A Shorter_List_B Result_A Result_B sorted_list

2     8,3,6,2  8,3            6,2            3,8      2,6      2,3,6,8

1(a)  8,3      8              3              8        3        3,8  
1(b)  6,2      6              2              6        2        2,6

0(a)  8        -              -              -        -        8
0(b)  3        -              -              -        -        3 
0(c)  6        -              -              -        -        6
0(d)  2        -              -              -        -        2
```

So, we started at level 2. Called ourselves recursively at level 1(a), 1(b). Then from level 1 called ourselves recursively again at level 0(a), 0(b), 0(c), 0(d) and then bubbled the merged results up all the way to level 2 again and then returned a sorted list.

Comment: "Every return will send back to the caller a sorted list of the elements it received as the input." Can you explain what you mean here? E.g let's say the last recursion (level 2) has only '8' in its array, so using RETURN NUM_LIST it returns '8'. Does it mean that it puts 8 to the input of its caller? Also putting '8' on the input of merge_sort level 1? So that it can then merge 8 and 3 (which is put with "return num_list" too) when merge_sort at level 1 is called?

Comment: @Coder88: It means that at every level, whatever list we get, we return another list with those same elements in sorted order. The last recursion is level 0 and not level 2 (I have started naming from the last level onwards to the top level). We get the full unsorted list at the top level. Then we keep breaking the list in half and reach level 0.

Comment: @Coder88: We receive the elements at level 2 and return from level 2 only. But to get sorted list at level 2, we go to levels 1(a) and 1(b) And level 1(a,b) go to level 0(a, b, c and d) to get the sorted lists.

Comment: @Coder88: See the table again. I changed its design. Do you understand it better now?

Comment: As I understood, "RETURN X" in a sub-routine means that it takes X from the sub-routine to his "original-routine" (or what to call it) and the "original-routine" continues its job with the value it got from the sub-routine. So when the sub-routine of "MergeSort(shorter_list_A)" is finished, it returns the value from that so "MergeSort(shorter_list_A)=that list" and then it moves that list to result_A using <-- symbol.

Comment: Here's a dummy Prezi presentation: https://prezi.com/5hxesubf5ibu/merge-sort-pseudocode/    blue arrows are call to a sub-routine (or to a recursion in this case). And red arrows are returning. Do you think this Prezi presentation can be used to explain Merge_sort? (I know it has no explanation-text on it, but it can be added or a voice-over explanation can be added).

Comment: @Coder88: Yes. The explanation you have given and the presentation, both are sound.

Comment: @Coder88: If you want to explain it to someone, keep the algo beside you and draw a *tree* (that is what it will become when you will draw the recursive calls) that shows what was sent to a *node* (i.e. the sub-routine) and what was returned.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to explain it just to be sure that I understand it right myself. But programming is a bit like a math, sometimes it's easy to understand but hard to explain.

Comment: @Coder88: whatever floats your boat. :)

Comment: But I wonder, where the last RETURN SORTED_LIST returns the list? I mean when the whole list is sorted, merged and put into SORTED_LIST (like 2,3,6,8) then there's RETURN SORTED_LIST. When executing the last RETURN SORTED_LIST, where does the SORTED_LIST returns? Or what happens?

Comment: @Coder88: To the original caller. The one who sent the unsorted list for sorting.

Comment: But what if there's no original caller? I mean if merge_sort is a desktop software where you type in some numbers and the software sorts them, where the last return returns the sorted_list?

Comment: @Coder88: In order to start this merge sorting, there will be some place where there will be a line like `merge_sort(inputList)`. This list will have numbers that are to be sorted. And the final return will bring the control back to this line itself. Usually the results are stored in some variable like `var sortedList = merge_sort(inputList)`.

Comment: @Coder88: The control will go to the `merge_sort()` only when it is called from somewhere. And when the execution finishes, the control comes back to the caller (be it software, or command line, or a line in another function). For example, in Java, the control comes to the `main()` when user calls it. `main()` is just a function like `merge_sort()`

Comment: ". . . And the final return will bring the control back to this line itself." What do you mean here?

Comment: @Coder88: For example in Java, when you would write `List<int> sorted_list = merge_sort(inputUnsortedList)`, then when the `merge_sort()` will finish, the control will come back to this same line and `sorted_list` will store the result of `merge_sort()`. Then the control will proceed to execute the next line in this code.